# Copy <img> from a <ul> to a <div>

Tags: jquery

I want to grab the images from this `<ul>`.

```
<ul class="tslider">
    <li>
        <div class="user_img"><img src="01.png" /> </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="user_img"><img src="02.png" /> </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="user_img"><img src="03.jpg" /> </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And put them in the corresponding `<div>` with class `bx-pager-item`.

```
<div class="bx-pager bx-default-pager">
    <div class="bx-pager-item"><a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="0" href="">1</a></div>
    <div class="bx-pager-item"><a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="1" href="">2</a></div>
    <div class="bx-pager-item"><a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="2" href="">3</a></div>
</div>
```

Here is what the result should look like.

```
<div class="bx-pager bx-default-pager">
    <div class="bx-pager-item"><a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="01.png" /></a></div>
    <div class="bx-pager-item"><a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="02.png" /></a></div>
    <div class="bx-pager-item"><a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="03.jpg" /></a></div>
</div>
```

I tried the following, but it's not working.

```
jQuery('.tslider > li').each(function(){
  var user_img = jQuery(this).find('.user_img').html();
  jQuery('.bx-pager').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('.bx-pager-item > a').html(user_img);
  });

});
```

Comment: Should the integers within the `<a>` elements be retained or removed? It seems they should be retained, but I don't know if that was deliberate or an oversight. Should the images themselves be *moved* or *copied* into those `<a>` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To empty the target `<a>` elements and move the `<img />` elements in, I'd suggest:

```
// getting a reference to the <a> elements, and emptying those
// elements of their current contents:
var links = $('div.bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.bx-pager-link').empty(),

// getting a reference to the <img> elements:
images = $('ul.tslider div img');

// using the append() method's anonymous function,
// i: the index of the current element in the collection,
// el: the current element-node (DOM node, not jQuery
// Object):
links.append(function(i,el) {

  // returning the <img /> element from the same
  // index in the collection in order to append it
  // to the current element:
  return images.eq(i);
});
```

```js
var links = $('div.bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.bx-pager-link').empty(),
  images = $('ul.tslider div img');

links.append(function(i, el) {
  return images.eq(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tslider">
  <li>
    <div class="user_img">
      <img src="01.png" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="user_img">
      <img src="02.png" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="user_img">
      <img src="03.jpg" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="bx-pager bx-default-pager">
  <div class="bx-pager-item"><a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="0" href="">1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bx-pager-item"><a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="1" href="">2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bx-pager-item"><a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="2" href="">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/y28cgfex/).

To append the `<img />` elements to the `<a>` elements, retaining the existing contents, simply remove the call to the `empty()` method:

```
var links = $('div.bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.bx-pager-link'),
  images = $('ul.tslider div img');

links.append(function(i, el) {
  return images.eq(i);
});
```

```js
var links = $('div.bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.bx-pager-link'),
  images = $('ul.tslider div img');

links.append(function(i, el) {
  return images.eq(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tslider">
  <li>
    <div class="user_img">
      <img src="01.png" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="user_img">
      <img src="02.png" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="user_img">
      <img src="03.jpg" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="bx-pager bx-default-pager">
  <div class="bx-pager-item"><a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="0" href="">1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bx-pager-item"><a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="1" href="">2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bx-pager-item"><a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="2" href="">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/y28cgfex/1).

And to copy the `<img>` elements into the target `<a>` elements, use the `clone()` method:

```
var links = $('div.bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.bx-pager-link'),
  images = $('ul.tslider div img');

links.append(function(i, el) {
  // as above, but having found the relevant <img />
  // we return its clone to the append() method and
  // append that clone, rather than the original <img />:
  return images.eq(i).clone(true, true);
});
```

```js
var links = $('div.bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.bx-pager-link'),
  images = $('ul.tslider div img');

links.append(function(i, el) {
  return images.eq(i).clone(true, true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tslider">
  <li>
    <div class="user_img">
      <img src="01.png" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="user_img">
      <img src="02.png" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="user_img">
      <img src="03.jpg" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="bx-pager bx-default-pager">
  <div class="bx-pager-item"><a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="0" href="">1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bx-pager-item"><a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="1" href="">2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bx-pager-item"><a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="2" href="">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/y28cgfex/2).

References:

- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you had to use

```
jQuery('.tslider > li').each(function(index){
  var user_img = jQuery(this).find('.user_img').html();
  jQuery('.bx-pager a[data-slide-index="'+index+'"]').html(user_img);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Boss Your Code is Working :)

Comment: Can you please explain Me Why you mentioned this "a[data-slide-index="'+index+'"] ", and What is the mining of "a[data-slide-index="'+index+'"]"